# Single linked list - data structure logic

Tags: java, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I have recently started focusing on coding exercises using data structures and its use cases. Below is my program to insert data in to single linked list where each node store the object of next node.This program works good. I wanted to understand how effective the below code,is the logic followed is valid and efficient. What are the real life use case of linked list when the nodes implemented with a custom behaviour. How to find the time complexity for the below program. Any pointers are really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class ExplainSingleLinkedList {

    private LinkedList<Node> integerLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();
    private TreeMap<String,String> userIdList = null;
    Node head = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExplainSingleLinkedList mainClass = new ExplainSingleLinkedList();
        mainClass.process();
    }

    private void process() {
        prepareInput();

        Iterator<Node> integerIterator = integerLinkedList.iterator();
        while(integerIterator.hasNext()){
            Node outputNode = integerIterator.next();
            System.out.println(outputNode.userId +" , " +outputNode.password +", "+ (outputNode.nextNode!=null ? outputNode.nextNode.userId:null));
        }
    }

    public void insert(String userId,String password){
        Node newNode = new Node(userId,password);
        if( head == null){
            head = newNode;
            integerLinkedList.add(head);
        }
        else{
            Node lastNode = integerLinkedList.getLast();
            if(lastNode.nextNode == null){
                if(head.nextNode ==null){
                    head.nextNode = newNode;
                }
                else{
                    lastNode.nextNode = newNode;
                }
            }

            newNode.nextNode = null;
            integerLinkedList.add(newNode);
        }

    }

    class Node
    {
        private String userId;
        private String password;
        Node nextNode;

        public Node(String firstName, String lastName){
            this.userId = firstName;
            this.password = lastName;
        }
    }

    private void prepareInput() {
        userIdList = new TreeMap<>();
        userIdList.put("a@in.com","a:123");
        userIdList.put("b@in.com","b:123");
        userIdList.put("c@in.com","c:123");
        for (Map.Entry entry : userIdList.entrySet()) {
            insert(entry.getKey().toString(),entry.getValue().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The output is below and it is working as expected

```
a@in.com , a:123, b@in.com
b@in.com , b:123, c@in.com
c@in.com , c:123, null
```

Comment: Maybe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a more appropriate forum for your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it wrong.

Usually, you insert always at the top of the linked list (the head node) and not at the end. Otherwise every addition of an element requires going through the whole list.

Or, if you want to store new elements at the end, a better way would be to store both the head and the tail, and to update the tail when you append.

Also, here it's not very clear you have implemented anything, as you use a Java LinkdList as backend. If you want to *implement* its behavior to understand how it works, don't use a class that does everything for you.

Comment: inserting at the end from my code means this  ```Node lastNode = integerLinkedList.getLast();```  ? my understanding of this logic statement is to get  previous node pointer and add the current or next node address to point

Comment: @Nag Yes, but `.getLast()`has a cost: for a linked list you must either loop through the whole list if you only have a pointer to the head, or you must keep track of both the head and the tail. Java's LinkdList probably doad the latter, but here you actually implemeted nothing: you just use the convenient LinkedList class and its methods. It's not inherently bad, and in real life you would probably use the builtin classes, but if the goal is to understand the logic as you stated, then you have done almost nothing to achieve this.

Comment: @Nag My advice: don't use LinkedList, TreeMap or any other builtin collection. Implement a class MyLinkedList that does everything from scratch (you could even make it generic, but it's not mandatory). And think about how to really insert an element. It's not difficult, and it's *very* instructive.

Comment: Ok ,so if i understand correctly from your comment, the algorithm or technique behind the working principle of a single linked list should be a own implementation rather using LinkedList itself. This is all started when i wanted to do small implementation with code storing data in a block ```blockchain``` in linked list fashion storing previous hash in the next node.

Comment: @Nag It's better if you want to understand, yes. If you just want a linked list in your program for some reason, and don't care about how it works, it's probably better to use the builtin class (and *only* it: here you have actually two lists, which is useless - one is a Java LinkedList, the other is only partly implemented and really uses LinkedList).